# PHP var_dump() returns NULL for assoc array

Tags: php, arrays, var, dump

I'm trying to get my coding started but I ran into a problem the following code works fine:

```
$acid=50;
$cocaine=0;
$hashish=0;
$heroin=0;
$ecstasy=0;
$smack=0;
$opium=0;
$crack=0;
$peyote=0;
$shrooms=0;
$speed=0;
$weed=0;

$drugs_current = array("acid" => $acid, "cocaine" => $cocaine, "hashish" => $hashish, "heroin" => $heroin, "ecstasy" => $ecstasy, "smack" => $smack, "opium" => $opium, "crack" => $crack, "peyote" => $peyote, "shrooms" => $shrooms, "speed" => $speed, "weed" => $weed);
```

But when I try to work with this:

```
$durgs_value_current = array("acid" => 1000, "cocaine" => 15000, "hashish" => 450, "heroin" => 5000, "ecstasy" => 10, "smack" => 1500, "opium" => 500, "crack" => 1000, "peyote" => 100, "shrooms" => 600, "speed" => 70, "weed" => 300);
```

The `var_dump()` returns NULL. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What variable are you trying to `var_dump()`? Note typo in variable `$durgs_value_current`

Comment: You sure you are not misspelling the variable name for the var_dump argument? I see a reference to drugs_current then in the other block durgs_value_current. I suggest you turn on more verbose messages, such as notices to see if you are referencing anything undefined.

Comment: Thanks...copied and carried the typo

Answer (score 0):

This https://3v4l.org/a5IRp running that exact code and var_dump'ing it seems to disagree.

Perhaps you have a typo with your `$durgs_value_current` when `var_dump()`'ing it?

Calling `var_dump($undefined_variable)` will result in a NULL and if you have error reporting turned of or are suppressing E_NOTICE's from logs then you won't receive an undefined variable error.